# Many_to_many --> FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: contains

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I have a two two models: `Doctor` and `Patient`. Doctor is defined as follows:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    patients = ManyToManyField('patients.Patient', related_name="%(class)ss", blank=True)
```

I want to get all the doctors that have a specific patient.
I tried:

```
doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(patients__contains=patient)
```

it doesnt' seem to work...any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`patients`** expects a ***integer*** value, which is not supported for ***`contains`*** query

Try

```
patient = 1
doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(patients=patient)
```

or

```
patients = [1,2,3,4]
doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(patients__in=patients)
```

Comment: So easy! Thanks i was kind of blocked